# apply both vectorized and non-vectorized function on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function which does this: it takes a given numpy array `A` and a given function `func` and applies the function to each element of the array.

```
def transform(A, func):
    return func(A)
```

`A` and `func` are supplied from outside and I do not have control over them. I would like the functions to work if they are vectorized functions such as `transform(A, np.sin)` but I also want to be able to accept normal numpy function e.g. lambdas like `transform(A, lambda x: x^2 if x > 5 else 0)`. Of course the second is not vectorized so I would need to call `np.vectorize()` before applying it. Like this: `transform(A, np.vectorize(lambda x: x^2 if x > 5 else 0))`... But I do nto want to impose this burden on the users. I would like a unified approach to all functions. I just get a function from outside and apply it.

Is there a method to decide which function requires vectorization and which does not? Something like:

```
def transform(A, func):
    if requires_vectorization(func):  # how to do this???
        func = np.vectorize(func)
    return func(A)
```

Or should I just vectorize all by default

```
def transform(A, func):
    func = np.vectorize(func)  # is this correct and efficient?
    return func(A)
```

Is this solution good? In other words, does it hurt to call `np.vectorize` on already vectorized function? Or is there any alternative?

Comment: You can at least measure the impact of vectorising an already vectorised function. I don't know how complicated your function would be, or how huge your data, but I doubt you'd notice a different for small arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [EAFP principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/1461210), you could first try calling the function directly on `A` and see if this raises an exception:

```
import numpy as np

def transform(A, func):
    try:
        return func(A)
    except TypeError:
        return np.vectorize(func)(A)
```

For example:

```
import math

A = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 5)

print(transform(A, np.sin))     # vectorized function
# [  0.00000000e+00   7.07106781e-01   1.00000000e+00   7.07106781e-01
#    1.22464680e-16]

print(transform(A, math.sin))   # non-vectorized function
# [  0.00000000e+00   7.07106781e-01   1.00000000e+00   7.07106781e-01
#    1.22464680e-16]
```

---

> does it hurt to call np.vectorize on already vectorized function?

Yes, absolutely. When you apply `np.vectorize` to a function, all of the looping over input array elements is done in Python, unlike in "proper" vectorized numpy functions which do their looping in C. From [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. **The implementation is essentially a for loop.**

I feel like this sentence should be written in bold all-caps.

Case in point:

```
In [1]: vecsin = np.vectorize(np.sin)

In [2]: %%timeit A = np.random.randn(10000);
np.sin(A)
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 243 µs per loop

In [3]: %%timeit A = np.random.randn(10000);
vecsin(A)
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop

In [4]: %%timeit A = np.random.randn(10000);
[np.sin(a) for a in A]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 12.5 ms per loop
```

In this example, applying `np.vectorize` to `np.sin` slows it down by a factor of ~50, making it about as slow as a regular Python list comprehension.

#### Edit:

For completeness, here's the "transformed" version. As you can see, the `try`/`except` block has a negligible impact on performance:

```
In [5]: %%timeit A = np.random.randn(10000);
transform(A, np.sin)
   ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 241 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is excellent answer. To make it just perfect, you could also time the proposed version with try-except structure. :)

Comment: See my update - the `try`/`except` block has essentially no impact on performance (as you'd expect)

Comment: The try-except block probably should also check for `ValueError`. This is what lambdas, e.g. `lambda x: 0 < x < 1`, raise in my tests.

Comment: In that particular case you should be using numpy's vectorized logical operators, e.g. `lambda x: (0 < x) & (x < 1)`. In general, I would expect that passing an array to a non-vectorized function ought to raise a `TypeError` rather than a `ValueError`. It's up to you what exceptions you want to catch, but keeping it as specific as possible will tend to make debugging easier.